# Different behaviour of unique_ptr vs raw pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, unique-ptr

I am struggling to understand the difference in behaviour of a raw pointer and a unique_ptr. I have `class A` with a variable `x` and `class B` with a pointer to an instance of `A`:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    int x;
};

A::A(int y) : x(y)
{
}

class B
{
public:
    B(A &);
    A *p;
};

B::B(A &a)
{
    p = &a;
}
```

This behaves as I would expect:

```cpp
int main()
{
    A a(2);
    B b(a);
    cout << a.x << " " << b.p->x << endl;
    a.x = 4;
    cout << a.x << " " << b.p->x << endl; 
}
```

gives

```sh
2 2
4 4
```

Changing the raw pointer to a std::unique_ptr gives a different result:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    int x;
};

A::A(int y) : x(y)
{
}

class B
{
public:
    B(A &);
    std::unique_ptr<A> p;
};

B::B(A &a)
{
    p = std::make_unique<A>(a);
}
```

gives

```sh
2 2
4 2
```

Have I fundamentally misunderstood something about unique_ptrs?

Comment: A raw pointer can point to something it does not own.  (And by some modern C++ conventions, that is the preferred idiom.)  A unique pointer owns the thing it points to.  So it has its own copy of it.

Comment: `p = std::make_unique<A>(a);` is a replacement for `new`. And you can't properly make `unique_ptr` point towards a reference as it calls delete in the destructor (unless you make one with custom destructor, but then why you do it?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make_unique` creates a fresh object, one that that `unique_pt` has exclusive access to. So in the second example you have two objects, not one and when you set change the value of `a.x` in the first object it doesn't effect the other object held by the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Right.   You can construct a unique_ptr from a raw pointer just as you'd construct any other object.   make_unique is a special helper that creates a new object managed by the unique pointer.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to obtain the desired behaviour (without raw pointers)? Or is this whole method simply a bad way of achieving the result?

Comment: Your program allocated a on the stack, and there's no way to make a smart pointer to an object on the stack.  Otherwise, you could rearrange your program to use shared_pointer, and allocate in main with make_shared instead of just a declaration.

Comment: I don't think you should fear using native pointers to make one object refer to another when neither one is managing storage of the other.

Comment: @operator Before asking how to obtain the desired behavior, you might want to state what the desired behavior is. (Guessing specs from code is unreliable.) Go back to your goals, write out requirements, and perhaps start a new question using your failed attempt to illustrate how you thought you might accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 1):

A unique pointer needs to own whatever it points to. Your code can be made to work - just substituting unique_ptr type and leaving everything else unchanged (no make_unique). But it will have undefined behavior, since you’ll create a unique pointer to an object that is owned elsewhere.

To compare apples to apples, the raw pointer code should read `p=new A(a);`. That’s what `make_unique` does.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the following expression from the smart pointer version:

> `std::make_unique<A>(a);`

"**make** a **unique** **`A`** from **`a`**" (*no mention of pointers!*)

The result is a `unique_ptr`, but when reading the expression, read it as making (an object whose type is) the template parameter. The function parameters are parameters to the constructor. In this case, you are making an `A` object from an `A` object, which pulls in the copy constructor.

Once you understand that the smart pointer version is making a new `A` object (and your raw pointer version does not), your results should make sense.

---

The "unique" in "unique `A`" might be tricky to understand. Think of it as an object that no one else can lay claim to. It might be a copy of another object, but, taking the role of the `unique_ptr`, it is *your* copy, *your* responsibility to clean up after, and no one else's. Your preciousss, which you will not share (c.f. `std::make_shared`).

Note that a local variable (like the `a` in the `main` function) is the responsibility of the compiler, so it is ineligible to be the object to which a `unique_ptr` points (or any smart pointer, for that matter).